# Указатели и const

Tags: c++

Увидел в одном коде такое вот описание:

```
const someclass *const *cls = ...
```

В С++ не силен, про `const` достаточно знаю.
Но вот это что? Зачем и как с этим работать?
Так и не понял, что за два указателя, вроде похоже на косвенную адресацию, но не уверен.

Буду рад совету и пояснению))

Update: `someclass` - любой класс, хоть пустой. Смысл не в нем, если что :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это указатель на указатель на объект данного класса. Первый const означает, что нельзя посредством данного указателя менять содержимое самого объекта. Второй const означает, что посредством этого указателя нельзя менять содержимое указателя, на который непосредственно указывает сам cls.

Comment: Следует отметить, что в C++ судя по всему не имеет значения как писать модификаторы доступа. Т.е. `const typename const *xxx` и `const typename * const xxx` - записи идентичные.

Comment: Идентичными будут записи const typename * XX и typename const * XX - получатся указатели на константу типа typename. Если написать const typename const * XX, должна выдаваться ошибка (g++ именно так и поступает).

Answer (score 1):

Читать следует справа налево: указатель на константный указатель на константу типа someclass. Это значит, что можно менять только саму переменную cls.